# How do I modify the text on a breadcrumb? 

Tags: breadcrumbs

How do I modify the text on a breadcrumb?

Is there a way to hook this generically so that I can change the text of any breadcrumb that is shown, regardless of the page?

Answer (score 1):

See [How to get rid of the "/blog"-page that displays all user-blogs (or change the breadcrumb-link)?](http://drupal.org/node/658736) I think that you will find an example on how to change a specific text of your breadcrumb.

For example, in your template.php file you can use `phptemplate_breadcrumb()` to search and replace text:

```
function phptemplate_breadcrumb($breadcrumb) {
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    $breadcrumb = preg_replace("/old text/", "new text", $breadcrumb); // This line will search and replace text.
    return '<div class="breadcrumb">'. implode(' >> ', $breadcrumb) . '</div>';
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs)  module on a number of projects. If you have the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module and consistent/clean URL aliases you can define the rules based on your address in the URL.

Comment: Does this also work for Views with contextual filters?

Comment: Yes it would work on views with contextual filters.